# Spring: Not setting column value in table

Tags: java, spring, database, null

I have the following table in which I have to set `orderID` against each `itemName`, my `itemName` set successfully but `orderId` sets null , When I print the value at console it prints right value.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem in my code?

```
List<String> items;
items=orderRequest.getOrderItem();
OrderItem orderItem=new OrderItem();
for (String temp : items) {
    orderItem.setItemName(temp);
    orderItem.setOrderId(order.getId());
    System.out.println("Order Id " + order.getId());
    orderItemRepo.save(orderItem);
    
}
```

Comment: Need to post your mapping structure, spring database connectivity code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your field name and also attach a debugger to figure out the real problem

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is that you are looping over potentially multiple items and setting the order id of the single orderItem every time.

The best way to figure out these kind of problems and get a feeling for what your code is doing is to attach a debugger and step through the code.